# canonical basis via Gelfand-Tsetlin basis

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups

Do there exist explicit formulas for the action of  Lusztig's canonical basis of
$U_q(\mathfrak n_+)$ in the Gelfand-Tsetlin basis of a Verma module for $sl(n)$?

Comment: should it exist ? What about classical limit q=1:  is Verma basis for sl(3) related to GT (if Yes - it should be known I think). As far as I understand in sl(3) "Verma basis" is limit of canonical bases (not 100%sure)

Comment: I don't know - but I would appreciate any information

Comment: I would suggest to ask Anton Gerasimov - they worked a lot on GT, moreover I had very vague memories that at some seminar he discussed exactly this question - but I am completely not sure... Side remarks: GT - is eigenbasis for GT commutative subalgebra (=integrable system). There is result by Vinberg that GT is limit of "top"=Gaudin=Hitchin=argument shift=Mishenko-Fomenko... There is GLn-GLm duality between GT and Jucys-Murphy (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/83150/).I have not heard any relation with canonical basis of any of these object. Except some paper by I. Frenkel on Macdonald<->CB